# How to align radio buttons with text to the left?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, radio-button, forms

Still working on a survey form project and am having trouble with button alignment.

As this example below shows, the first radio button should be in line with the text to the left which is the question:
[image: Desired result]

However, I have played around with `display` and other CSS elements, even trying `margin` and `padding`, none of which seem to make my buttons line up correctly. My buttons shown below:
[image: My result]

And my relevant code shown below that produced my incorrect result:

**HTML**:

```
 <label for="recommend">*How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
      <div class="button-group">
        <div class="label-button"> <label for="recommend"><input type="radio" id="recommend" class="input-box" name="recommend" value="definitely">Definitely</label>
        </div>
<div class="label-button">
        <input type="radio" name="recommend" class="input-box" name="recommend" value="maybe">Maybe</label>
      </div>
      <div class="label-button">
        <input type="radio" name="recommend" class="input-box" name="recommend" value="not-sure">Not sure</label>
  </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#survey-form {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.row > * {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row label {
  text-align: right;
}
.input-field {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  height: 40px;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.input-select {
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.button-group {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}
form {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.label-button {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

Codepen link also here: https://codepen.io/jerryd2304/pen/qvERZL

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried

Comment: @VarshaDhadge I know, I accidentally clicked post early, so I had to edit and finish the question. Apologies.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `align-item: flex-start`

```
.row.align-item-start {
    align-items: flex-start;
}

 <div class="row align-item-start">
```

[Here is the codepen link for the same](https://codepen.io/dasg1/pen/WmQgqy)

Comment: I tried this, gave me this result: https://codepen.io/jerryd2304/pen/qvOMrG

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!